# How do I make a specific command with a insertable value with Python? Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I would like to have a command that has the availability of this:

`>paypal 5`

Bot's message: Please send $5 to this email:

Anyone able to help me out with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean `arguments` by "insertable" values.

You can add arguments like this:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def paypal(ctx, cash): # cash being the argument
    await ctx.send(f'Please send {cash}$ to this email:')
```

Answer (score 0):

In a function wrapped by `@bot.command` decorator, you can pass arguments with type hints casting types, and also using `*` operator:

```
@bot.command()
async def paypal(ctx, cash: int):
    await ctx.send(f'Please send {cash}$ to this email: ')
```

This command can be invoked in Discord this way:

```
>paypal 15
Please send 15$ to this email:
```

Assuming `>` is your bot's prefix.